# Is the Google Play Developer Console the only way to see a list of compatible devices for my Android app?

Tags: android, google-play-console

After reading through the Android developer documentation, I see that it is possible to see a comprehensive list of supported devices for a given .apk file [via the Google Play Develop Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en&visit_id=1-636325992022992589-3358423945&rd=1).

Is there an alternative way of doing this, which does not require uploading an .apk to the Developer Console?

Comment: why has this question been voted down without even leaving a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Without uploading apk, how will you trace which device are supported? Nothing better than native Google developer console which traces list of all supported devices, countries, device name, version etc.,

Answer (score 1):

There are several parameter that are considered before generating the list of supported devices, few of those parameters are:
 1. Minimum SDK version
 2. Target SDK version
 3. Support for camera hardware (if your application uses camera)
 4. Support for front camera (if your application uses front cam)
 5. Support for sensors that your app uses.
 6. Support for opengl libraries (if your app uses it)
 7. Support for supported screen sizes.
 8. Support for calling or sms, if your app needs to make a call or send sms, etc

Basically you declare these addional requirements in your app manifest or you generate different layout files for tablets and other unusual devices.

**There are many more parameters to consider to generate the list of supported, since all the devices are registered with Google, Google play store is the best and most reliable source to get the list.**

> And the most important thing, List of supported devices is greatly
>   affected by the settings that you have on playstore like ratings,
>   country, category, etc. So to get the exact list, your apk should be
>   on PlayStore, at least as a draft.